# Loading a very big csv file by using apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to load huge csv files by using Apache Spark.

So far, I loaded different files by using Apache Spark's `read` method. I did not face any problem. However, the file sizes were not big, they were around 100 megabytes.

Now I received some scalability questions like:
"What happens if the file does not fit into driver's memory?"

How does the `spark.read` method work? Is it loading the csv file into the driver's (master node) memory? I would appreciate any idea, experience or documentation.

sample code:

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("hugecsvfile.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does not load the file in memory. It will read the file once to define the schema but that's all. It is better to provide the schema otherwise, it will be long just to define it. At least, you could set some option so it reads only a portion of your file.

After that, any transformation/action will be executed on chunk of your file.

Answer (score 1):

from the code sample you posted it seeems the `hugecsvfile.csv` is already in the master node . but on disk.

so spark will read you file and send data to the core nodes in the cluster. Spark automatically spill data on disk on those core nodes if required.
- you can explicitly tell it to cache the computation on disk but if you dont then it will be recomputed on the file.

spark only brings data to master node's memory ( doesn't spill to disk on master node ) when you execute an action.

Comment: if I change my code as below, will the whole file be loaded in the master node's memory?
`code`
    df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("s3n://bucket-name/hugecsvfile.csv")
    df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)    
    some jdbc queries on the database
`code`

Comment: since its a single file ( huge file say 500gb ) it will first bring the file down to master node. in this case on disk and then send it to cluster.

ideally you would store this huge data set in to small files equivalent to a factor of the no of executors you can provision on ur spark / yarn cluster. that will allow you to load the data quickly.

also, if you have a huge file , you can use s3-dist-util and break it into chunks and load it on hdfs or spark cluster.